# How to generate hash value from list of files in google drive

Tags: c#, hash, google-drive-api, md5

I am able to generate the hash value of each respective file in Google Drive. My question is how do I store these hashes in like a hashtable or hash set so that I can perform comparison of hash later so that I can remove the duplicated hashes.

```
public static List<GoogleDriveFiles> GetDriveFiles()
    {
        DriveService service = GetService();

        // define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest FileListRequest = service.Files.List();

        //listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        //listRequest.PageToken = 10;
        FileListRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, size, createdTime, md5Checksum, fileExtension, modifiedTime, mimeType)";

        //get file list.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = FileListRequest.Execute().Files;
        List<GoogleDriveFiles> FileList = new List<GoogleDriveFiles>();

        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                GoogleDriveFiles File = new GoogleDriveFiles
                {
                    Id = file.Id,
                    Name = file.Name,
                    Size = file.Size,
                    CreatedTime = file.CreatedTime,
                    MD5hash = file.Md5Checksum,
                    Extension = file.FileExtension,
                   ModifiedTime = file.ModifiedTime,
                   MimeType = file.MimeType,

            };
                FileList.Add(File);
            }
        }

        return FileList;



    }
```

I am unsure how should I approach this problem. Am I able to compute  a hashtable in that function or should I build another constructor.

Comment: Why not just use `Dictionary<int, string>` to map the 32 bit Md5Checksum to the filename? Beware though - two files with the same Md5Checksum aren't necessarily identical; you'd still need to compare the entire contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hashset for MD5 Checksum of Files in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57535636/hashset-for-md5-checksum-of-files-in-google-drive)